# Declare type of instance variable on controller

Tags: crystal-lang, amber-framework

I have a crystal-lang project on Amber framework with Jennifer.cr and I'm getting this error on my controller:

```
Can't infer the type of instance variable '@companies' of CompanyController
@companies = Company.all
```

The controller is:

```
class CompanyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @companies = Company.all
    render("index.slang")
  end
end
```

When I try to solve the problem this way:

```
class CompanyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @companies : Array(Company) = Company.all
    render("index.slang")
  end
end
```

I got another error:

```
instantiating 'CompanyController#index()'
in src/controllers/company_controller.cr:7: declaring the type of an instance variable must be done at the class level

    @companies : Array(Company) = Company.all
```

How can I solve this "easy" problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to use instance variable here. Local variable is a way Amber app uses by default (and they are accessible in views):

```
class CompanyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    companies = Company.all
    render("index.slang")
  end
end
```

But if you want to use an instance variable due to some reason, you need to declare and initialize it at a class level or [follow other type inference rules](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/type_inference.html).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned using a local variable here is the most elegant solution. For people ending up here with a similar error message but in a different context, read below:

The second error message already points to the right solution, the following code should work too:

```
class CompanyController < ApplicationController
  @companies : Array(Company)?

  def index
    @companies = Company.all
    render("index.slang")
  end
end
```

Comment: Don't should be Array(Company) ?

Comment: This won't work. First, `@companies` should be initialized in a constructor or be nillable. Second, `Company.all` returns `Jennifer::QueryBuilder::ModelQuery(Company)`, not `Array(Company)`. But thanks for explaining the concept.